# Django query: How to filter objects by todays day, time and after 30 minutes?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

I've got a field in models like:

```
class Sample(models.Model): 
    start = models.TimeField(verbose_name=_("start time")) 
    end = models.TimeField(verbose_name=_("end time"))
```

Now, a need to filter my object by "start" and "end" attributes, e.g, it should filter all objects by todays day, time and time within 30 minutes.

I tried:

```
 models.Sample.objects.filter(start__gt=datetime.now(),
                             end__lt=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30))
```

I know, that filtering with two filters is a mistake.. and my code not filtering by today's day. For example, i need to have all objects today on (Tuesday), from 12h till 12:30h

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean filtering with two filters is a mistake? You are using only one filter function with two conditions. Also can you clarify as to what you are trying to filter. I'm still confused what you mean by "all objects by todays day, time and time within 30 minutes."

Comment: I mean that i am chaining filters and in my case it's a mistake. I have an objects which starts and ends by time ranges, e.g starts 10:15 - ends 12:00, 12:00 - 15:30... I need to filter objects, and obtain only those objects which starts at present day, present time, within 30minutes.

Comment: In order to be able to filter by present day, you will have to change your fields to use `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

You have used used [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield) in your model declaration. That stores only the time with no data for day, month or year.

> A time, represented in Python by a datetime.time instance

So instead of using `datetime.now()` use `datetime.now().time()` and instead of `datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30)` use `(datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30)).time()`

To be able to include filtering by day, month, year and time replace TimeField in the model with [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield). The filtering using `datetime.now()` and the `timedelta(minutes=30)` will work as in your original question.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mention, that i also have "week_day" and "week_type" in models: ( week_day = models.IntegerField(choices=WORK_DAYS, verbose_name=_("day of week")) –

Comment: That should work fine then, just use .time() on datetime object as in my answer.

Comment: when i changed timedelta.(minutes=30).time(), a got an error: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'time'

Comment: It is (datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30)).time(). Note the brackets properly

Comment: ok, thanks, it works. One more question, how i can filter by a week_day and time in the same query?

Comment: You can filter(start__gt=datetime.now(),
                             end__lt=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30), week_day=3) or you can do filter(...).filter(week_day=3). Either adding comma separated to same or concatenating two filters

Comment: Thanks, so is my syntax is good? Sample.objects.filter(datetime.weekday(datetime.now())).filter(datetime.time(datetime.now())).filter(datetime.time(datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes = 30)))

Comment: No
Use  models.Sample.objects.filter(weekday=<Your week day>).filter(start__gt=datetime.now().time(),
                             end__lt=(datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30)).time())

Comment: and the last: how to obtain automatically todays week day with datetime? i mean how to get todays week day without handwriting like "your week day"

Comment: datetime.now().isocalendar()[2] will give you day of the week, that is for Friday you will get 5, Thursday 4, Monday 1, Sunday 7